# Can we span separate instance of COM server(exe)

Tags: winapi, com

I would like to have multiple test clients, and would like to associate one one com server exe for serving each of test clients.

So far what I can see is in my system there is only one COM server exe running which is serving all my test clients.

Please advice how to achieve this in COM.

Regards
Ashish

Comment: The COM server decides this when it specifies the REGCLS in its CoRegisterClassObject() call.  Nothing that a client app can do to overrule that decision.

Answer (score 3):

Your first server probably calls `CoRegisterClassObject`, which means that the second client finds an available class object (using `CoGetClassObject`, probably via `CoCreateInstance`).

`CoRegisterClassObject` has optional [`REGCLS`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms679697%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) flags which control reuse. Sounds you want `REGCLS_MULTI_SEPARATE`.

Comment: Thanks for Info... but I am not getting this method defined anywhere in my COM exe.. However I can see "DllRegisterServer" is there in proxystub dll project for the same COM server.

Comment: I don't follow. First you say you have an EXE server (out of process) now it's a DLL (in-process)? Those are completely different things in this case.

Comment: I mean to say when we create a com exe(out of proc), one more project will get created by ATL wizard for generation of proxy stub dll.

Comment: Oh, right, non-standard interface which requires marshalling code. That has to go somewhere, yes. Still, the real EXE has to register the class factory somewhere. Could be down in ATL code, though.

Comment: please advice me some way to to address the below mention problem.  I have multiple client exes, I would like to have one dedicated com object out of proc for each client exe, which will server the request for that particular client exe....How should I create my com server in this case, I have tried both STA and MTA but no result.   I cant have normal IPC(shared memory, pipe, window messages) between these two exe that is the reason I have selected COM approach to address this.

Comment: @user2893899: As I said, make sure that your class factory is registered properly. STA versus MTA are irrelevant. Obviously, you **can** have normal IPC since you **do** have IPC. COM is built on top of DEC RPC.